# why there is no output of lsattr and how to resolve it

Tags: linux, security, openssh, xattr

The normal output of `lsattr` is below

```
# lsattr /etc/fstab 
---------------- /etc/fstab
```

but I have a host ,when I run `lsattr`, there is no output display to me, just like below.
[image]

my os version is `centos 7.9.2009`. I reinstalled e2fsprogs-1.42.9-19.el7.x86_64 but it seams helpless.

Why I noticed this is because I could not operator `/usr/sbin/sshd` neither delete or copy etc. It caused me unable to reinstall the sshd service

[image]

Below is the error of installing openssh-server
[image]

I run `strace /usr/sbin/sshd` on the ob01 which is a bad system,the output is below

```
[root@ob01 ~]# strace lsattr /usr/sbin/sshd
execve("/bin/lsattr", ["lsattr", "/usr/sbin/sshd"], 0x7ffd56518b68 /* 17 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x945000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb10a84a000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=34304, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 34304, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb10a841000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@\316\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=174576, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2268928, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb10a400000
mprotect(0x7fb10a425000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb10a625000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7fb10a625000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=19248, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109744, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb10a1fc000
mprotect(0x7fb10a1fe000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb10a3fe000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fb10a3fe000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`&\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2156592, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb10a840000
mmap(NULL, 3985920, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb109e2e000
mprotect(0x7fb109ff2000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb10a1f1000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c3000) = 0x7fb10a1f1000
mmap(0x7fb10a1f7000, 16896, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb10a1f7000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb10a83e000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fb10a83e740) = 0
access("/etc/sysconfig/strcasecmp-nonascii", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/sysconfig/strcasecmp-nonascii", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mprotect(0x7fb10a1f1000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb10a3fe000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb10a625000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x6dd000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fb10a84b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fb10a841000, 34304)           = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)     = 3
close(3)                                = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x945000
brk(0x966000)                           = 0x966000
brk(NULL)                               = 0x966000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=106176928, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 106176928, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb1038eb000
close(3)                                = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x966000
getuid()                                = 0
getgid()                                = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getegid()                               = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
open("/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb10a849000
read(3, "MemTotal:       263972636 kB\nMem"..., 1024) = 1024
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fb10a849000, 4096)            = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7fb109e64400}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7fb109e64400}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7fb109e64400}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fb109e64400}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fb109e64400}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fb109e64400}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fb109e64400}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fb109e64400}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fb109e64400}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fb109e64400}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fb109e64400}, 8) = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="ob01", ...}) = 0
stat("/root", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0550, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0550, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getpid()                                = 28390
open("/usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26970, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 26970, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7fb10a843000
close(3)                                = 0
getppid()                               = 28383
getpgrp()                               = 28383
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=0x4414a0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7fb109e64400}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7fb109e64400}, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, {rlim_cur=640*1024, rlim_max=640*1024}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
open("/bin/lsattr", O_RDONLY)           = 3
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7fff7292e310)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
read(3, "#!/bin/sh\n", 80)              = 10
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=640*1024, rlim_max=640*1024}) = 0
fcntl(255, F_GETFD)                     = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
dup2(3, 255)                            = 255
close(3)                                = 0
fcntl(255, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
fcntl(255, F_GETFL)                     = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(255, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=10, ...}) = 0
lseek(255, 0, SEEK_CUR)                 = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
read(255, "#!/bin/sh\n", 10)            = 10
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
read(255, "", 10)                       = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

And the good system output is below

```
[root@ob03 ~]#  strace lsattr /usr/sbin/sshd 
execve("/usr/bin/lsattr", ["lsattr", "/usr/sbin/sshd"], 0x7ffcd663f778 /* 21 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x246d000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f742d042000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26333, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 26333, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f742d03b000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libe2p.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\37\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=33704, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2128240, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f742cc1a000
mprotect(0x7f742cc21000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f742ce20000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f742ce20000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libcom_err.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@\25\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=15856, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109928, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f742ca16000
mprotect(0x7f742ca19000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f742cc18000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f742cc18000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`&\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2156592, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f742d03a000
mmap(NULL, 3985920, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f742c648000
mprotect(0x7f742c80c000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f742ca0b000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c3000) = 0x7f742ca0b000
mmap(0x7f742ca11000, 16896, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f742ca11000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200m\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=142144, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2208904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f742c42c000
mprotect(0x7f742c443000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f742c642000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7f742c642000
mmap(0x7f742c644000, 13448, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f742c644000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f742d039000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f742d037000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f742d037740) = 0
access("/etc/sysconfig/strcasecmp-nonascii", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/sysconfig/strcasecmp-nonascii", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mprotect(0x7f742ca0b000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f742c642000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f742cc18000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f742ce20000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x601000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f742d043000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f742d03b000, 26333)           = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f742d037a10)         = 6671
set_robust_list(0x7f742d037a20, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7f742c432860, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f742c43b630}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7f742c4328f0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f742c43b630}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=10240*1024, rlim_max=10240*1024}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x246d000
brk(0x248e000)                          = 0x248e000
brk(NULL)                               = 0x248e000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=106176928, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 106176928, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7425ee9000
close(3)                                = 0
lstat("/usr/sbin/sshd", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=852856, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/sbin/sshd", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=852856, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/sbin/sshd", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
ioctl(3, FS_IOC_GETFLAGS, 0x7ffdd67d6c3c) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f742d041000
write(1, "---------------- /usr/sbin/sshd\n", 32---------------- /usr/sbin/sshd
) = 32
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Is there anyone who has any ideas about the situation and how to resovle it?

Best wishes.

Comment: Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read and the content will not show up in search engine results. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: Are the involved filesystems possibly mounted read-only? Why are you specifically interested in `lsattr`? It's unclear what the main issue is. At the moment, your issue with installing OpenSSH seems to be of lesser importance while you're really just interested in knowing why you don't get the expected output from `lsattr`. If that's the case, then maybe remove the part of the question having to do with OpenSSH?

Comment: Because I think the issue of openssh is caused by  some reason that related to the situation of `lsattr` output nothing,  I couldnot delete `/usr/bin/sshd` as you seen

Comment: it could be selinux, I would do some basic tests, like try to create a file on the filesystem containing /usr, also I would run `strace lsattr /etc/fstab` and see where it fails.  Also, I would look at kernel logs with `dmesg` and see if anything odd stands out

Comment: @toppk I have disabled selinux, and I run `strace lsattr  /etc/fstab`,  it return `+++ exited with 0 +++` , I think that means no error happend，it is so strange that troubled me for a long time.

Comment: there should be some details inside strace did with either a stat or openat call.  I suggest running the same strace lsattr command on a good system so you know what it should look like when it is functioning properly.

Comment: Indeed, There are some differences, but I do not understand the output, could you give me some advise. I put both of the output  in the body of the question

Answer (score 0):

```
open("/bin/lsattr", O_RDONLY)           = 3
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7fff7292e310)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
read(3, "#!/bin/sh\n", 80)              = 10
```

It looks like `/bin/lsattr` has been replaced with a script in the "bad" system. These lines tell me that the first 10 bytes of `/bin/lsattr` are now `#!/bin/sh<newline>`.

```
dup2(3, 255)                            = 255
close(3)                                = 0
fcntl(255, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
fcntl(255, F_GETFL)                     = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(255, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=10, ...}) = 0
```

And it looks like the size of `/bin/lsattr` is exactly 10 bytes, so it looks like the real `/bin/lsattr` has been replaced with an essentially empty script that does nothing. This does not look good.

Your system has probably been compromised: the `/usr/sbin/sshd` from the `openssh-server` package may have been replaced with a backdoored one that probably sends copies of any passwords entered to an intruder, and the replacement of `lsattr` may have been just to make it harder to get rid of the backdoor. There may be other illegitimate modifications too.

In a situation like this, you should disconnect this system from the network ASAP, and see [this question on Information Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39231) for further advice.

But in a nutshell: you should treat all passwords used to login to this system as compromised. If the username+password pairs used on this system are used anywhere else, they should be changed immediately.

You should then backup any important data that is on this system, then completely format and reinstall it. Yes, really. The intruder may have done any number of modifications to the system to make it serve them and to make it easier for them to regain access to it even if you attempt to "clean" it.

If you restore this system from an old backup (risky), you should carefully verify that the backup does not already have the intruder's modifications in it, and then make sure the restored system will not be accessible from the internet until you have installed all available updates and verified the integrity of all already-installed packages.

Answer (score -1):

Your version (and mine, lsattr 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023) on Debian Bookworm) *possibly* needs the -a switch (or another switch).

```
root@debian:~# lsattr /Hitachi/
root@debian:~#

root@debian:~# lsattr -a /Hitachi/
----i---------e------- /Hitachi/.
--------------e------- /Hitachi/..
```